# Bootstrap nav-tabs not displaying tab-content in mvc?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm Dynamically generating/loading  tabs from controllers using list.

```
<div class=""row>
<div class="col-xl-3">
<!-- Tabs nav -->
  <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills nav-pills-custom" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Controls)
       {
          <a class="nav-link mb-5 p-3" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#@item.Control" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
               <span class="font-weight-bold small text-uppercase">@item.Control</span>     //tabs 
         </a>
       }
  </div>
  <!-- /Tabs nav -->
</div>
<div class="col-xl-9">
<!-- Tabs content -->
  <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Controls)
        {
         <div class="tab-pane fade shadow rounded bg-white show active p-5" id="@item.Control" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
          <h5 class="hk-sec-title">@item.Control</h5>                //tab content
        }
  </div>
   <!-- /Tabs content -->
</div>
```

The thinks is I managed to generate tabs nav bar but not tab content.
For more look and fill of tabs here is fiddle to follow:  https://jsfiddle.net/bootstrapious/68o3pmcv/

Comment: What does `ViewBag.Controls` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html has various errors and typos e.g.

`<div class=""row>` should be `<div class="row">`

Also the `row` div and the `tab-pane` div do not have a closing tags.

But the main issue with your code is that you are adding `show active` classes to all `tab-pane` divs. I added a boolean flag to the `ViewBag.Controls` items and only add `show active` classes when the flag is true. Final result:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3">
        <!-- Tabs nav -->
        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills nav-pills-custom" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Controls)
            {
                <a class="nav-link mb-5 p-3 shadow @(item.Active ? "active" : null)" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#@item.Control" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold small text-uppercase">@item.Control</span>
                </a>
            }
        </div>
        <!-- /Tabs nav -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-9">
        <!-- Tabs content -->
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Controls)
            {
                <div class="tab-pane fade shadow rounded bg-white p-5 @(item.Active ? "show active" : null)" id="@item.Control" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                    <h5 class="hk-sec-title text-dark">@item.Control</h5>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <!-- /Tabs content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I tested above code with this data:

```cs
ViewBag.Controls = new[]
{
    new { Control = "test1", Active = false },
    // Selected by default. You can change this but only add active true to one item.
    new { Control = "test2", Active = true }, 
    new { Control = "test3", Active = false },
    new { Control = "test4", Active = false }
};
```